# Determining the optimal excel chart major unit

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, vba

one of my tasks is updating a presentation with zillion charts. 
Since there are 4 charts per slide it is important that the major unit on a chart is set so that the charts are legible.

I found a way to code some steps and cut the time significantly but one of the missing pieces is determining the major unit of a chart.

So the question is:
***Is there a way to to determine through formulas or vba what should be the major unit in a date type x axis based on the dynamic  start date and end date (I want last date to be shown on a graph)***

Bellow is the example:

- dates are having one week interval
- I need the final date that shows up in pivot to be on the chart
- I need the chart dates to be legible given that it will take quarter of a slide

[chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whqbM.jpg)

I tried going through similar questions and one of the solutions (that didnt work for me) was:

- using Days360 to calculate number of days between start and end date
- adding 1 to be inclusive of start and end day
- dividing that number of days with number of wanted ticks minus one
- so far I was using 27 as a number of ticks, based on legibility experience

If I find a way to precisely determine a number to be used I will use it as a reference # for my macro that changes all the applicable charts

Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: What didn't work with your second solution?  It seems like a legitimate way to determine major intervals.  The biggest issue I could see is that the number between ticks could be odd numbers (not whole days) in which case you will need to optimize the solution with some sort of limits (max 35 ticks, min 30 ticks) and try to optimize a solution that uses whole number intervals (or whole week intervals).

Comment: Hi gtwebb
You are probably right.I just put number as 27 because thats the usual number of ticks I end up with. (I dont really care about their number as long as they are not dense and are readable). Solution doesnt work because it happens that I dont see the final date at the end and that is one of the requirements. 
Is there a way to add another column and somehow optimize number of ticks as well via formula?